# Can't access 2nd level attributes from scope variable in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working with MEAN.js application. I come accross one strange problem.

```
$scope.currentUser = Authentication.user;
console.log($scope.currentUser);
```

output:

```
    {"_id":"5579c9a4f3d71f8c2a4f1e3d","email":"ilesh@gmail.com","country":"US",
"gender":"Male","name":"Ilesh Patel"}
```

when I execute this than it prints all the data of currentUser but as soon as I do

```
$scope.currentUser = Authentication.user;
console.log($scope.currentUser.name);
```

then I get **undefined**. I don't know why I am not able to get name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know AngularJs but it looks like the result is json encoded if you can output it like this to the console. Decode the result with `JSON.parse` before using it.

```
$scope.currentUser = JSON.parse(Authentication.user);
```